# Windows Authentication ASP.NET 3.5 with Smart Cards not allowing user name/password

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008, windows-authentication, smartcard

Is it possible to not allow user name and password when using windows authentication?

I have an ASP.NET Web App on DomainB that users, accessing from browser in DomainA, can automatically log into using smart card with Windows Authentication, which maps client cert to domain(b) user account, and logs into the app as the user. All of this is working, however if the cert doesn't map, etc....then Windows Auth prompts for user name and password. If they enter the user name and password it works and I want to specifically prevent this, and only allow smart card access/login. There is no login.aspx/forms auth being used.

This is on 2008R2/IIS7.5/impersonation